# How to calculate the Result Number using query SQL

Tags: sql-server

I use the query below to find the student name jason from all the tables in my database,i can see easily and know how many jason has appear in each table in database.

But now i want to calculate how many jason did actually appear in the database from all table, i need a Total of all the jason that appeared.

How to calculate the Jason instead of just showing at the Result?

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(20) = 'Student_Name'
DECLARE @VariableValue VARCHAR(20) = 'Jason'

SELECT 'select count(*) from ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE ' +     @ColumnName + ' = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @VariableValue)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
```

After the code above i will get the command below:

```
select count(*) from dbo.ClassA WHERE Student_Name = Jason
select count(*) from dbo.ClassB WHERE Student_Name = Jason
select count(*) from dbo.ClassC WHERE Student_Name = Jason
select count(*) from dbo.ClassD WHERE Student_Name = Jason
```

And execute those command i will get the result as :

The Result of this code will probably be, and what i want is the total of this number appear, 5+1+0+0+1 = 7

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the generated query as a subquery:

```
'SELECT SUM(cnt) AS Total FROM (' + @InnerSQL + ')t'
```

Your final query should be:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(20) = 'Student_Name'
DECLARE @VariableValue VARCHAR(20) = 'Jason'

DECLARE @InnerSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @FinalSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @InnerSQL  = @InnerSQL +
    'select count(*) as cnt from ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' = @VariableValue UNION ALL' + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName

IF LEN(@InnerSQL) > 0 BEGIN
    SELECT @InnerSQL = LEFT(@InnerSQL, LEN(@InnerSQL) - 11) 

    SELECT @FinalSQL = 
    'SELECT SUM(cnt) AS Total FROM(' + @InnerSQL + '    )t'

    SELECT @FinalSQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @FinalSQL, N'@VariableValue VARCHAR(20)', @VariableValue = @VariableValue
END
```

Additionally, you should execute your dynamic sql using `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Good Answer ! Thank you for your help! clear ,detail and awesome

Comment: do you know how to change the "no column name " in the picture into its table name itself ? or show it beside

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using the while loop and then working within that while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query

```
select SUM(cnt) from 
(
select count(*) from dbo.ClassA WHERE Student_Name = Jason
UNION all
select count(*) as cnt from dbo.ClassB WHERE Student_Name = Jason
UNION all
select count(*) as cnt from dbo.ClassC WHERE Student_Name = Jason
UNION all
select count(*) as cnt from dbo.ClassD WHERE Student_Name = Jason
) as a
```

Comment: I don't think i can key in tale name one by one for this, maybe using a for loop to modify this code, or maybe as above answer, use information schema to get all table name and data. There may be hundreds of tables in the database, so write the table name one by one is not a good idea. but ur idea is still awesome